# If $x\in R$ and $a$ be any positive real number then

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

If $x\in R$ and $a$ be any positive real number then $|x|<a \implies -a<x<a$ and conversely.

My Attempt:
For all $x\in R$, $|x|\geq x$

Given, $|x|<a$
So, $x\leq |x| < a$
$$\implies x<a$$
By similar process, we get $x>-a$
Thus, $-a<x<a$.

But, How do I get converse proof?

Comment: What is  your definition of $|a|$? The converse direction follows from this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can prove the equivalence in one stroke, if you note that
$$|\,x\,|<a\iff x^2<a^2\iff x^2-a^2<0,$$
so you don't have an absolute value any more.

Comment: I didn't get it.. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you learn to solve quadratic inequalities?

Comment: Yeah.. I know some basics regarding that...

Comment: Then the equivalence should be obvious: a quadratic polynomial  has the sign of its leading coefficient, except between its (real) roots, if any.

Answer (score 0):

If $x<0$ then $-x>0$ thus $  a>-x >-a \Rightarrow -x<a$

If $x>0$ then $ a>x>-a \Rightarrow x<a$

Thus $|x|<a$

$|x|=\begin{cases}\
      -x &, x<0\\
       x & ,x>0\\
       0 & ,x=0\\
      \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

$|x|$ it's a distance between the point $x$ in the $x$-axis and the origin.

Thus, for $a>0$ we obtain:
$$|x|<a$$ it's
$$-a<x<a.$$
Draw it!