# Why is $\left( -a,a \right)$ equal to $|x| < a$

Tags: interval-arithmetic

I have a problem understanding the equality of an open Interval as given $\left( -a,a \right) = \{x \in R | -a< x< a\}$ to say $|x| < a$..

Maybe someone can get me intuitive to understand that?

Comment: Note that $\left( -a,a \right) = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid a\leq x\leq b\}$ is already wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry, corrected it

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2435975 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035964 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2829096 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3201277

Comment: I wouldn't say they're equal. $|x|<a$ suggests there exists some specific $x\in\mathbb R$ whose absolute value is less than $a$. It doesn't specifically refer to an interval. And if you saw it outside of any other context, I think you's be more likely to interpret it as referring to some specific $x$ rather than an interval.

Comment: @JohnForkosh More precise would be {$x\in \mathbb R\ |\ -a<x<a$} or {$x\in \mathbb R\  |\  |x|<a$}

Comment: @Peter Sure. But note that the op already said it exactly that way (after three tries:). His specific question's in the Subject. And I think the answer's just a matter of interpretation, like I suggested. So the op himself will have to clarify exactly what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the end points are not contained in the interval, we have $|x|<a$ instead of $|x|\le a$. A number $x$ is between $-a$ and $a$ ($-a<x<a$) if and only if its absolute value is smaller than $a$.

Comment: but how can $x$ get negative? I thought the abs of $x$ can only be positive.. so why is the lower bound of $-a$ relevant for the interval?

Comment: While the *absolute value* of $x$ cannot be negative, it is still possible for $x$ itself to be negative. As an example, if $|x|<10$, then it is possible for $x$ to be negative, e.g. $x$ could be $-9$, since $|-9| < 10$.

Comment: It is true that $|x|$ cannot be negative, but $x$ can be.

Comment: i got it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was going to explain it mathematically but since you asked for an intuitive understanding, I'll go for it:

Look at the graph of $|x|$ (tip: try to graph on Desmos), it looks like never-ending $2$-sides of a right-angled triangle at the origin and pointing upwards, with the $y$-axis as the bisector of this triangle.

Now if you put $y<a$ for some $a$, you'll notice that this restricts the interval of $x$ to $(-a,a)$ on the graph of $|x|$, so this settles it!